# How to do data analysis (like counts, ucounts, frequency) with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ("i", 1, 'GlIrbixGsmCL'),
    ("i", 1, 'GlIrbixGsmCL'),
    ("i", 1, '3IMR1UteQA'),
    ("c", 1, 'GlIrbixGsmCL'),
    ("i", 2, 'GlIrbixGsmCL'),
], columns=['type', 'cid', 'userid'])
```

**Expected output like:**
[image: expect output]

**For more details:**

```
i_counts, c_counts      => df.groupby(["cid","type"]).size()
i_ucounts, c_ucounts    => df.groupby(["cid","type"])["userid"].nunique()
i_frequency,u_frequency => df.groupby(["cid","type"])["userid"].value_counts()
```

Looks it's a little complex for me, how to do with pandas to get the expected result?

**The related screenshots:**
[image: screenshots]

Comment: Have a look at agg function

Comment: I also tried code `df.groupby(["cid","type"]).agg(counts=("userid", np.size), ucounts=("userid", "nunique")).reset_index()` , but don't know how to do the next to get what I want as expect

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this:

```
aggfuncs= {
    'counts': ('userid', 'count'), 
    'ucounts': ('userid', 'nunique'),
    'frequency': ('userid', lambda S: S.value_counts().to_dict()),
}

output = df.groupby(['cid', 'type']).agg(**aggfuncs).unstack()
output.columns = output.columns.map(lambda tup: '_'.join(tup[::-1]))
```

output:

```
     c_counts  i_counts  c_ucounts  i_ucounts          c_frequency                           i_frequency
cid
1         1.0       3.0        1.0        2.0  {'GlIrbixGsmCL': 1}  {'GlIrbixGsmCL': 2, '3IMR1UteQA': 1}
2         NaN       1.0        NaN        1.0                  NaN                   {'GlIrbixGsmCL': 1}
```

I think that is the core of what you want. You will need some cosmetic amendments to get the output exactly as in your example (e.g. fillna etc.).

Answer (score 0):

#### STEPS:

1. Extract the `id_numbers` from `user_id` and convert them to `int type`.
2. Use `groupby` and `agg` to evaluate `count`/`ucount` / `frequency.
3. use `pivot` to restructure the table.
4. flatten the columns and `reset_index` if required.

```
df['userid'] = df.userid.str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
k = df.groupby(["type", 'cid']).agg(count=('userid', 'count'), ucount=(
    'userid', 'nunique'), frequency=('userid', lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())).reset_index()
k = k.pivot(index=[k.index, 'cid'], columns='type').fillna(0)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
      count      ucount      frequency              
type      c    i      c    i         c             i
  cid                                               
0 1     1.0  0.0    1.0  0.0    {1: 1}             0
1 1     0.0  3.0    0.0  2.0         0  {1: 2, 2: 1}
2 2     0.0  1.0    0.0  1.0         0        {1: 1}
```

Then to transform columns:

```
k.columns = k.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join(x[::-1]))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
       c_count  i_count  c_ucount  i_ucount c_frequency   i_frequency
  cid                                                                
0 1        1.0      0.0       1.0       0.0      {1: 1}             0
1 1        0.0      3.0       0.0       2.0           0  {1: 2, 2: 1}
2 2        0.0      1.0       0.0       1.0           0        {1: 1}
```

#### updated answer (according to your edited question):

```
k = df.groupby(["type" , 'cid']).agg(count = ('userid' ,'count') , ucount = ('userid', 'nunique') , frequency=('userid', lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())).reset_index()
k = k.pivot(index=['cid'], columns ='type').fillna(0)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
    count   ucount  frequency
type    c   i   c   i   c   i
cid                     
1   1.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 {'userid001': 1}    {'userid001': 2, 'userid002': 1}
2   0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0   {'userid001': 1}
```

`NOTE`: use `df.userid = df.userid.factorize()[0]` to encode `userid` if required.

Comment: I tried your code, looks I got Error like with df.assign code =>  KeyError: "[('userid', '<lambda>')] not in index"

Comment: But is this what you need? or not? @SilenceHe.

Comment: By the way, the **userid** is somthing like random user cookie, so they are not regular string like {userid + number}, so maybe `df.userid.str.split('userid').str[1].astype(int)` is not suit for this scenario.

Comment: yes, it's what I what, looks I have something wrong with the output result, will update the result for this question

Comment: Made few more changes @SilenceHe

Comment: Sorry for the wrong output result before, already updated the question and show correctly output, row index 0 and 1 should be merged to the 1 row but not 2 row, and the real userid string like "GlIrbixGsmCL" for cookie id used, which means it can't covert to int type